# Question about an argument with a conflicting premises and conclusion

Tags: logic

I have a homework problem where I have to state if an argument is valid, conclusive or neither. However I am struggling to wrap my head around this one.

The argument goes:

> Generally, a flood occurs only if there is too much water. Yet a flood
>   is occurring, although there isn't too much water. So a flood isn't
>   occurring.

I am having difficulty as the premises states that there is a flood occurring, however then the conclusion states that there is not.

So far I have attempted this method:

```
F: There is a flood occurring 

W: There is too much water

W -> F

F && ~W

Therefore ~F
```

However I am not too sure what to make of that.

Can the premises just be wrong like that and the argument still be valid?

Comment: "generally" means that it is not always true that... So, no valid inference here.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh okay, so "generally" is the same as using "sometimes".

Comment: "Generally" means "in most cases", "typically", the correct conclusion is that this case is atypical.

Comment: The 1st premise is "if F, then W". The second one: "F and not-W" is equivalent to "not(if F, then W)". Thus, **if we onit** "generally", we have two contradictory premises.

Comment: From contradictory premises, everything follows; thus, **if we omit** "generally", the argument is valid.